# (Qt C++) int Won't Add a Number?

Tags: c++, qt, int, operators

:)
Hello,

I have been scratching my head over this for so long. I'm just trying to add 4294967296 to my negative int (-432 to +431) I have this

```
int temp_int;

    temp_int = ui->SpawnX->value(); //From spinbox
    if(temp_int < 0)
    {
        temp_int = temp_int + 4294967296;
        qDebug() << temp_int;
    }
```

But no matter what I try, the temp_int just stays the same, I double check with the qDebug. What am I doing wrong!!!?

Earlier in my program:

```
 //Get spawn point and fix negative numbers
    temp_hex = level.mid(18+level.indexOf("030006537061776e58"), 8);
    HexToInt(temp_hex, SpawnX);
    temp_hex = level.mid(18+level.indexOf("030006537061776e59"), 8);
    HexToInt(temp_hex, SpawnY);
    temp_hex = level.mid(18+level.indexOf("030006537061776e5a"), 8);
    HexToInt(temp_hex, SpawnZ);
    if(SpawnX > 432)
        SpawnX = SpawnX-4294967296;
    if(SpawnY > 432)
        SpawnY = SpawnY-4294967296;
    if(SpawnZ > 432)
        SpawnZ = SpawnZ-4294967296;
```

In this case, SpawnX,Y,Z are int's and can range anywhere from 0 to 4294967295.

Comment: Use `UINT_MAX` instead of writing out the number manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that adding 4294967296 to -432 will give you +431.

That's not correct (and I'm wondering how you made that assumption).

4294967296 is 2<sup>32</sup>. Adding 2<sup>32</sup> to a 32-bit `int` will *probably* just wrap around and give you the original value. Actually signed integer overflow has undefined behavior, but the common implementation just ignores all but the low-order 32 bits -- and all the low-order 32 bits of 4294967296 are 0. It's clearer in hexadecimal: 4294967296 is 0x100000000, and dropping the 33rd bit gives you 0x00000000.

If you have -432 and you want +431, there are various ways to do it; the most straightforward is probably just

```
temp_int = -temp_int - 1;
```

An even simpler way is:

```
temp_int = 431;
```

but that's probably not what you want.

It would help if we understood what you're trying to do.

> In this case, SpawnX,Y,Z are int's and can range anywhere from 0 to 4294967295.

If you want that range, you need to use a 32-bit *unsigned* type. If `unsigned int` is 32 bits, then it can represent values from 0 to 4294967295. And in that case, adding 4294967296 *will* wrap around and give you the original value; unsigned overflow, unlike signed overflow, is well defined.

Comment: That is not what I'm aiming for. I am converting it to hex format and I need the number to be big. Example. -2 becomes fffffffd   which is 4294967293  (-432 to 431) was simply a range that int could be.

Comment: @mc360pro: Then you should probably be using `unsigned int` rather than `int`.

Comment: @mc360pro: Right. If you assign a negative value to an `unsigned int`, the conversion gives you a positive value; small negative values are converted to large positive values.

Comment: So is it impossible for me to have an int with a value that large? This doesn't make sense to me because I never go over 4294967295. I made it an uint, however, later in my program it HAS to be an int, and whenever I try to convert it, it resorts back to a small negative value

Comment: @mc360pro: Assuming `int` is 32 bits, the range of `unsigned int` is 0 to 4294967295, and the range of `unsigned int` is (probably) -2147483648 to +2147483647. If you need a wider range, you'll just have to use a bigger type.

Comment: That makes no sense. Because ints like SpawnX can and do sometimes contain 4294967295. How come temp_int can't?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33383/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-mc360pro)